# Magmi On the fly category creator/importer - do not unassign products from existing categories

Tags: php, magento, magmi

I am looking at using the On the fly category creator/importer plugin for Magmi to import product/category assignments to my Magento store.

Is there any way when using this plugin to NOT remove existing categories assignments?

Currently, if I import a product and assign it to "category A" using Magmi, then also assign it to "category B" within Magento - if I then re-import it using Magmi, the link to "category B" is removed.

Due to the nature of our setup, the above behaviour is not desirable. Which is a shame. I am aware I can achieve the above using the standard category importer - but for other reasons the on-the-fly creation would be better!

Any thoughts much appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make Magmi keep existing categories assignments, add a new field named `category_reset` in your datasource and set it to `0`

Comment: That's what I was missing. The documentation is very unclear in places, I see now that option was mentioned on the standard category importer documentation. But not on the on-the-fly which from what I read replaces that. I've got what I need running I think I'll offer to help that with that!